# WooCommerce Number of Downloads

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a WordPress / WooCommerce driven shop which is used only for people to sign up and publish virtual downloadable products. Is there any way to track the amount of times a user's product has been downloaded (uniquely)? I literally have no idea where to start looking for a solution for this so if anyone could help me out that'd me awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can get it by function `total_sales`, but when your users can download items more than once, it is necessary to combine with download permissions

Answer (score 0):

Use code below:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_product_sold_count', 11 );

function custom_product_sold_count() {
   global $product;
   $units_sold = $product->get_total_sales();
   if ( $units_sold ) echo '<p>' . sprintf( __( 'Units Sold: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ) . '</p>';
}
```